# How to get the same output when using the `difference` function of a HashSet?

Tags: rust

I'm using HashSets to find the differences between 2 vectors

```
let a = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "f".to_string(), "e".to_string()];
let b = vec!["a".to_string(), "c".to_string(), "d".to_string()];

let a_set: HashSet<&String> = HashSet::from_iter(a.iter());
let b_set: HashSet<&String> = HashSet::from_iter(b.iter());

let missing_a = b_set.difference(&a_set).cloned().collect();
let missing_b = a_set.difference(&b_set).cloned().collect();

assert_eq!(missing_a, vec!["c".to_string(), "d".to_string()]);
assert_eq!(missing_b, vec!["f".to_string(), "e".to_string()]);
```

Currently, the order of `missing_a` and `missing_b` is not the same each time it is run, so the test can fail.

How can I make sure that `HashSet::difference` returns the same output every time?

Comment: This is by design; consider trying: https://docs.rs/indexmap/latest/indexmap/set/struct.IndexSet.html

Comment: Any reason you don't collect into a `HashSet` instead of a `Vec`? Also you might want to do `.as_deref()` instead of `.cloned()` so you can compare directly with `&str`s.

Comment: You may want to use a `BTreeSet` instead of a `HashSet` if you're storing strings. A `BTreeSet` will give you an ordered iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hash-based containers typically do not have deterministic ordering.  From the documentation for [`HashSet::iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.iter):

> An iterator visiting all elements in arbitrary order.

Just collect the results into a container type that does not take order into account when comparing container values for equality -- such as `HashSet`:

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "f".to_string(), "e".to_string()];
    let b = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "c".to_string(), "d".to_string()];

    let a_set: HashSet<&String> = HashSet::from_iter(a.iter());
    let b_set: HashSet<&String> = HashSet::from_iter(b.iter());

    let missing_a = b_set.difference(&a_set).cloned().collect::<HashSet<_>>();
    let missing_b = a_set.difference(&b_set).cloned().collect::<HashSet<_>>();

    assert_eq!(missing_a, HashSet::from_iter([&"c".to_string(), &"d".to_string()]));
    assert_eq!(missing_b, HashSet::from_iter([&"f".to_string(), &"e".to_string()]));
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5043762d040e97f1edceba9ed6e643d8))

Comment: This is a good solution, but I need the order to be constant. I opted to use a `BTreeSet`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @PitaJ, I decided to use a `BTreeSet`:

```
let a = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "f".to_string(), "e".to_string()];
let b = vec!["a".to_string(), "c".to_string(), "d".to_string()];

let a_set: BTreeSet<&String> = BTreeSet::from_iter(a.iter());
let b_set: BTreeSet<&String> = BTreeSet::from_iter(b.iter());

let missing_a = b_set.difference(&a_set).cloned().collect();
let missing_b = a_set.difference(&b_set).cloned().collect();

assert_eq!(missing_a, vec!["c".to_string(), "d".to_string()]);
assert_eq!(missing_b, vec!["f".to_string(), "e".to_string()]);
```